# M Project vs Sproutcore

Tags: javascript-framework, sproutcore

I cant decide between this two options.

M Project vs Sproutcore

I'm building an application that will be primary served on mobile but has to be viable on desktop.

Mproject is on the edge with number and variability of his prebuilded widgets and may happen that I will need some more or at least alter some behavior.
So this is kind of down side of Mproject. But it looked for first review that Mproject need less code for basic stuff.

And the second problem comes with the skins. I will basicaly need reskin everything a lot. The design of app has to be very unique.
So I want to know which of them is easily to reskin not just by theme-roller and similar stuff.

I would appreciate any other JavaScript-only frameworks recommendations.

Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of application are you building so you should take care with my answer.

M-Project solved our problems fine, and help us to make it clear code ... when you understand how it works. It requires a bit of hard work, the documentation is a bit poor and is a new project where some things are not yet implemented. You can change application look modifying HTML and CSS so I think you should have no problems with this.

Also you can download their code and modify it without problems, it is easy to read and modify if you need any specific behavior.

On other side, I never used Sproutcore, it have a really nice look. But documentation say it is focused on desktop applications. Probably you will not have too much problems to adapt the output HTML for mobile devices, I guess.

Lastly, I think you can take a look on [Lungo.js Framework](http://www.lungojs.com/).

Best regards.